# Annotating Text with PyCamera

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, ascii, picamera

For a project I'm mesuring the temperature with a termocouple.
Now I want to display the measured temperature in a video using PiCamera and the `picamera library`. There is a given function called `annotate_text` which is suitable of annotating text when given in Ascii.
My question would be if it is possible to convert the measured value (`type float`) into string an then ascii and overlay or if someone knows another way.

```
import picamera
import datetime as dt

camera = picamera.PiCamera(resolution=(1280, 720), framerate=24)
camera.annotate_background = picamera.Color('black')
camera.start_recording('test.h264')
start = dt.datetime.now()
while (dt.datetime.now() - start).seconds < 30:
   value = hat.t_in_read(channel)
   camera.annotate_text = value
   camera.wait_recording(0.2)
camera.stop_recording()
```

Comment: This seems like something that you could just try and see what happens. Is there a specific question?